# Definition of receiver class

Tags: terminology

What is the definition of a reciever class? Is this the containg class of a field? For example, if field b is in a class named Foo, then Foo is the reciever class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the term comes up in iPhone-Programming more often. In Objective-C you do not call a method on an object but you send a message to that object and the object decides whether it will handle it or not. Since Objective-C borrwos from Smalltalk you should probably look for the term in that context. What language do you use?

Comment: Hi, I use C# (that's the context this question is in).